# Wsdl to Java OUT parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl2java, out-parameters

As stated in this link: [link](http://frightanic.com/software-development/wsdl-to-java-out-parameters-holders-vs-return-types/)

there are two ways to deal with OUT parameters when generating java classes from wsdl which handle OUT parameters

- holder types
- return type

When using Eclipse's Web Service and Web Service Client wizards I am getting classes generated according to first way mentioned above (holder classes).

Is there a way to configure eclipse in such a way, that I would be able to generate my java code using second way mentioned earlier (one return type)?

As far as I know after browsing the internet I am intrested in so called "BARE" mode while generating service classes.

Comment: Did you try wsdl2java tool from command line?

Comment: I'll give it a try, but knowing that Eclipse uses this tool I assumed that it is configurable from Eclipse's level.

Comment: I do not know how to use with Eclipse IDE.  Check different command line arguments and give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface adnotation:

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```